# How can I know when a call end?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can my android app detect a dropped call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153815/how-can-my-android-app-detect-a-dropped-call)
>   [Detecting outgoing call and call hangup event in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497061/detecting-outgoing-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android)

I'm making an app that needs to start an intent when a call ends, but I dont know how to do so,
i used this in a Call Reciver to track a new call:

```
    telephony.listen(imPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497061/detecting-outgoing-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **TelephonyManager**

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                String stateString = "N/A";
                switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    stateString = "Idle";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    stateString = "Off Hook";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    stateString = "Ringing";
                    break;
                }

                System.out.println("state-:: " + stateString);
            }
```

Comment: how can i recive the state back in the broadcast reciver?

Answer (score 1):

Simply when the radio state goes back to idle. But you cannot detect if the connection was not established.