# How to detect call drop in android

Tags: android

How to detect that call is dropped due to bad network.
I have reserched alot and know that call is disconnected but not able to differentiate that call is dropped by caller or receiver or it is dropped by bad network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153815/how-can-my-android-app-detect-a-dropped-call

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

Comment: I have already read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153815/how-can-my-android-app-detect-a-dropped-call.   But problem in this is we cannot detect whether call is dropped by bad network or caller or receiver has cut the call

Comment: You would combine that with a listener that listens for connectivity events, and write some logic that can deduces what caused the call drop.